# JAXB (un)marshalling of xsd types: xsd:base64Binary and xsd:hexBinary

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

JAXB maps both `xsd:base64Binary` and `xsd:hexBinary` types to `byte[]`.

Given that I have a schema/a DOM Element representing each of these types such as:

`<foo>ABCD</foo>` for xsd:hexBinary and 
`<foo>YTM0NZomIzI2OTsmIzM0NTueYQ==</foo>` for xsd:base64Binary ,

it's not clear how JAXB 2.1 handles it.

`JAXB.unmarshal(new DOMSource(node), byte[].class)` does not like the payload.

Neither does the following:

`JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(byte[].class);
 ctx.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(node);`

What's the correct way of handling these types?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "does not like the payload" mean?  Provide some error messages and/or stack traces.

Comment: When one does: Element element = document.createElement("foo");
element.setTextContent("ABCD");
byte[] ba = JAXB.unmarshal(new DOMSource(element), byte[].class); The resulting ba[] has values: [0, 16, -125].

Answer (score 13):

The conversion between byte[] and the hexBinary or base64Binary representation is done via a correspondent XmlAdapter.

by default JAXB uses the included [HexBinaryAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/HexBinaryAdapter.html) for converting byte[] to a String.
I don't know if there is also an XmlAdapter which converts from/to base64 but that is no problem:

You can easily implement it yourself using an own XmlAdpater:

```
public final class Base64Adapter extends XmlAdapter<String, byte[]> {
    public byte[] unmarshal(String s) {
        if (s == null)
            return null;
        return org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(s);
    }

    public String marshal(byte[] bytes) {
        if (bytes == null)
            return null;
        return org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
    }
}
```

You can specify on a field/getter_setter level what should be processed by which adapter:

```
private class DataTestClass {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Base64Adapter.class)
    public byte[] base64Data = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(HexBinaryAdapter.class)
    public byte[] hexbinData = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

}
```